# Как залить цветом слева и справа от блока до края экрана?

Tags: css, css3

Макет фиксированной ширины посередине экрана. Необходимо для части блоков сделать горизонтальную заливку по бокам до краев экрана. Такое решение с псевдоэлементами вызывает горизонтальный скролл на ширину родительского элемента. Подскажите как сделать без скролла.

```html
<!doctype html>
<style>
.width { margin:0 auto; width:1300px;}
.block { padding:10px 0; width:100%; background:#97cc64; position:relative;}
.block:before, .block:after {top:0; bottom:0; content:''; background:#97cc64; position:absolute;  width:100%;}
.block:before { right:100%} 
.block:after { left:100%}
</style>

<div class="width">
  <div class="block">
     Block content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как по мне, проще сделать так:

```css
.wrapper{
      background: linear-gradient(to left,#00364f 50%,#01a4a6 50%);
}

.content{
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

С фиксированной шириной 1300px скрол будет в любом случае на экранах меньше 1300px. В данном случае можете попробовать для body {overflow-x:hidden;}

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сейчас этот костыль стоит. Из-за этого яндекс не признает сайт адаптивным. Техподдержка пишет что на iPhone 5 горизонтальный скролл

Comment: Попробуй заменить width на max-width

Comment: Тогда исчезают псевдоэлементы

Comment: пример https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/vb60ys5c/ -  max-width + псевдоэлементы = работает

Answer (score 0):

Можно, если высота блока известна и фиксирована.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #afa;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50vw);
  z-index: -100;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Второй вариант, если высота неизвестна + адаптивность (смотреть на полном экране):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  background-color: green;
}

.third {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="second">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
      up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
      Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
      in section 1.10.32.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="third">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
      from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но высота заранее неизвестна. Каждый блок может быть произвольной высоты + желательно решение для адаптивности

Comment: Добавил другой вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант будет адаптивным и не будет выызывать горизонтальный скролл.
Если ширина экрана будет >1300px, то вы увидите те самые блоки по краям.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.width {
  display: block;
  background: #97aa64;
}

.block {
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px; /**/
  background: #97cc64;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="width">
  <div class="block">
    Block content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть более простой вариант!

```css
.bg-1 {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.p-t-45 {
  padding-top: 45px;
}

.p-r-218 {
  padding-right: 218px;
}

.p-b-5 {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.p-b-45 {
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}

.p-l-218 {
  padding-left: 218px;
}

.jc-sb {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.text-a-c {
  text-align: center;
}

.tit4 {
  font-family: Times;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.txt1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #8E8E8E;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<link 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="bg-1 p-t-45 p-r-218 p-b-45 p-l-218">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xxl jc-sb text-a-c">
        <div class="col-1"></div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <p class="tit4 p-b-5">Честность</p>
          <p class="txt1">Вы можете следить <br> за процессом</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <p class="tit4 p-b-5">Поддержка</p>
          <p class="txt1">Мы всегда на связи</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <p class="tit4 p-b-5">Профессионализм</p>
          <p class="txt1">Наши сотрудники <br> знают свое дело</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <p class="tit4 p-b-5">Цели</p>
          <p class="txt1">Выполняем <br> поставленные задачи</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```